# Send ajax json to WCF Service

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, wcf

I know I'm totally missing something, but I'm new to json and services so bear with me..

This is json:

```
json['data'] = { "country":tableName, "from":currency, "to":dataCurrency, "amount":values };
```

This is my method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "/Convert",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetRate(Rates obj);
```

And my object

```
[DataContract()]
public class Rates
{
    [DataMember(Name="data")]
    public List<Rate> data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract()]
public class Rate
{
    [DataMember(Name = "amount")]
    public List<int> amount { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "country")]
    public string country { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "from")]
    public string from { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "to")]
    public string to { get; set; }    

}
```

But the post data its always null and I get an exception of object reference not set to bla...

My question is, how can I receive and treat my json obj

Comment: I think you are missing `content-type` header?

Comment: I'm using cross-domain and when I set the content-type on my ajax call I get an error 400 and it transforms my request method to OPTIONS.

Comment: even though my web.config is like this:  `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, Content-Type, Origin" />`

Comment: Do you use `JSON.stringify(Your JSON)`  and content type as `application/json; charset=utf-8`